# EF creating an unwanted field in database

Tags: entity-framework

I've hit a snag while building a .net mvc site. I have 2 related objects and am struggling with properly linking them. Specifically:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressCategory")] // <-- EF adds field to below object's table
    public int AddressCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual AddressCategory AddressCategory { get; set; }
}

public class AddressCategory
{
    public int AddressCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Adding the **[ForeignKey]** data annotation to the **Address** object results in EF adding an **Address_AddressId** column to the **AddressCategory** table, which I don't want (or need) to happen.

I've tried to omit the ForeignKey attribute, but then I run into other errors because .net can't link the tables (e.g. Unknown column 'Extent1.AddressId' in 'field list'). Additionally, I wouldn't be able to use:

```
var addresses = db.Addresses.Include(l => l.AddressCategory);
```

Is there any way to link the 2 tables without EF adding an additional column to the AddressCategory table?

Comment: What is the relation between those two entities? One AddressCategory can have many Address entities?

Comment: Correct: one AddressCategory could be used by many Address records e.g. "Residential", "Commercial", etc. An Address record will only have 1 AddressCategory.

Comment: Lets put public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses {get;set;} to AddressCategory class.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @cloudikka for responding. After much trial-and-error I seem to have gotten it to work simply by omitting any ForeignKey reference from either object. I let EF rebuild the database and perform all scaffolding (CRUD forms) and they have been created perfectly.

My take-away is that foreign key attributes should be used for parent-child relationships, but not for look-up tables. I clearly have much to learn about asp.net mvc!